# browsersync can't open multiple browsers

Tags: gulp, browser-sync

In my `Gulpfile.js` in serve task, the option `browser: ['Google Chrome','Internet Explorer']` doesn't work; it only opens google chrome, not the internet explorer. Was I just wrong in using that option?

Answer (score 1):

According to the docs, you need to set it like:

```
// Open the site in Chrome & Firefox
browser: ["google chrome", "firefox"]
```

Try using lower case.

Answer (score 0):

Try just "explorer" or just "chrome" buddy. This worked for me. In default-config.js use this  - 
browser: ["chrome", "firefox", "explorer"]